# Yii2 Module setup in advanced template

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have created a module in frontend folder path is `frontend/modules/module-name/Module.php`. I am getting `ReflectionException error as Class app\modules\module-name\Module does not exist`. In frontend/config/main.php i have added this configuration

```
 'modules' => [
     'module-name' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\module-name\Module'
    ]
```

Can anyone help why i am getting this ReflectionException error

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are using an advanced template, folder path is `frontend/modules/module-name/Module.php`, but you are requiring `app\modules\module-name\Module` class. It looks like a namespace from basic application template.

In case of advanced template, make sure that `Module.php` file is in `frontend/modules/module-name` folder, has a namespace `frontend\modules\module-name` and you are requiring `frontend\modules\module-name\Module` class.

Comment: I was using same namespace path starting with app/modules/ModuleName for other modules why now only for this new module i am getting this error

Comment: @Rohini Check the namespace of this file and make sure it matches required namespace.

Comment: might be small or capital letter issue will be there... Other then that looks ok